# What does IconName do in creature_template?

Tags: azerothcore

There's a column in creature_template called IconName but I went to the creature CPP and the only thing they do with this is query it.
I have a bug I'm working on and I wonder if I could use this column for what I need.
There's an NPC that you talk to and he's a quest giver and you have to talk to him in a gossip style "tell me more about X". However he also sells stuff and since he has vendoritems then the icon that appears as you hover him is the bag due to his unitflags. Using this iconname I could use this as an exception and just ignore these flags, and display a white baloon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it on [this pr](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/4844/files) to allow creatures who have a vendor flag and Speak icon flag to display a White chat balloon. Prior to this change, this column remained unused.